# ef core include always create left join

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to filter data by navigation properties, so I want 'include' to generate 'inner join' query. I set the property 'required' as other question's answers said, but it did not work.

```cs
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int? Rating { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
                .HasMany(b => b.Posts)
                .WithOne(p => p.Blog)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction).IsRequired();
}
```

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
        var blogs = context.Blogs
              .Include(blog => blog.Posts.Where(blog => blog.Content == "xxxx"))
              .ToList();
}
```

Generated sql：

```sql
      SELECT [b].[BlogId], [b].[OwnerId], [b].[Rating], [b].[Url], [t].[PostId], [t].[AuthorId], [t].[BlogId], [t].[Content], [t].[Rating], [t].[Title]
      FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [p].[PostId], [p].[AuthorId], [p].[BlogId], [p].[Content], [p].[Rating], [p].[Title]
          FROM [Posts] AS [p]
          WHERE [p].[Content] = N'xxxx'
      ) AS [t] ON [b].[BlogId] = [t].[BlogId]
      ORDER BY [b].[BlogId], [t].[PostId]
```

Expected sql：

```sql
      SELECT [b].[BlogId], [b].[OwnerId], [b].[Rating], [b].[Url], [t].[PostId], [t].[AuthorId], [t].[BlogId], [t].[Content], [t].[Rating], [t].[Title]
      FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
      INNER JOIN (
          SELECT [p].[PostId], [p].[AuthorId], [p].[BlogId], [p].[Content], [p].[Rating], [p].[Title]
          FROM [Posts] AS [p]
          WHERE [p].[Content] = N'xxxx'
      ) AS [t] ON [b].[BlogId] = [t].[BlogId]
      ORDER BY [b].[BlogId], [t].[PostId]
```

version : ef core 5.0

Comment: `Include` is used for eager loading, not generating JOINs. The query you used says `get all Blogs along with any posts containing xxxx`. It doesn't say `only get blogs with posts containing xxxx`. A left join is the correct JOIN type

Comment: Why do you expect an inner join with include? That would create side effects. Include should at least always return all source table entities, not leave some out when you add an include.

Comment: Perhaps you should be thinking about querying `Post` and including `Blog`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes , my goal is the second one.  I use ` .Where(blog=> blog.Posts.Any(blog => blog.Content == "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")) ` to achieve my goal——`only get blogs with posts containing xxxx`

Comment: @Silvermind Thank u for ur suggestion